# Mutual exclusion expected with comparison operators

Tags: python, logic, mutual-exclusion

I am not a programming genius, but just in the beginning of this year, when being taught propositional logic my teacher told me (and it was quite obvious) that if P is True, not(P) or ~P was False, and the opposite if P was False.

Reading the Python docs about creating custom objects, I found that they claim that `a==b` being `True` does not imply that `a!=b` is `False`. This confused my mind as I thought that `!=` was the negation of `==` and therefore, whenever evaluating with `==` returned a boolean result, the expression `!=` would always evaluate to the opposite... And as far as I know, `not(True)` evaluates to `False` and `not(False)` evaluates to `True`. Can someone please help me understand how this happens? Perhaps with an example?

I read about this right [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__)

quoting:

> The truth of x==y does not imply that x!=y is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because they are operators which can be custom implemented separately, and the operators themselves (at a high level) don't dictate that if `x==y` is true then `x!=y` is false (one **could** implement them such that that relationship does not follow).

The key is the statement in the doc that follows that:

> Accordingly, when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()`
>   so that the operators will behave as expected

When both are implemented, then there is an explicit relationship between the operators.

Comment: So does this mean that that behaviour is not self exclusive just when we are talking about custom objects?

Comment: No. While customization is essentially the reason there are no implied relationships, since there are no implied relationships, one should always keep the documented behavior in mind. (Behind the scenes, both `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` need to be defined to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Ok. so would it be "correct" to have `__ne__()` defined as `not(self.__eq__())`?

Comment: Sure. The key is that if you define it that way, you're explicitly making the relationship; it's just not made for you implicitly.

Comment: FYI if you want python to fill in the "implied relationships", use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Largely this is just because we *can* do silly stuff:

```
class MessedUpShizzle:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True

MessedUpShizzle() == MessedUpShizzle()
#>>> True

MessedUpShizzle() != MessedUpShizzle()
#>>> True
```

If you're wondering what this if *for*, I'd imagine it's largely for symmetry (and thus a pretty implementation). Consider that `x < y` and `x >= y` are *not* inverses:

```
{1} < {2}
#>>> False

{1} >= {2}
#>>> False
```

so we need both `__ge__` and `__le__` separately defined.